# NotImplementedException thrown when TextBox Constructor is called in my Unity project

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine

I have been using the Windows.Forms libraries in my Unity project as a GUI so that the user can export and import paticular files. I have recently had the thought to use it for text input because the ui is sleeker than the Unity text input in doing so I made this snippet of code.

Code:

```
public TextInputDialog()
        {
            form = new Form();
            label = new Label();
            textBox = new TextBox();
            buttonOK = new Button();
            buttonCancel = new Button();

            buttonOK.Text = "Save";
            buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            buttonOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
            textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
            buttonOK.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
            buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

            label.AutoSize = true;
            textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonOK.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

            form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOK, buttonCancel });
            form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.AcceptButton = buttonOK;
            form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;
        }
```

However when I ran the engine to test the text input window and it resulted in a NotImplementedException that occurs when the TextBox constructor is called and when I try to define a new Control array.

Log:

```
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt16 (System.Object ptr, System.Int32 ofs) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
System.Drawing.Font.FromLogFont (System.Object lf, System.IntPtr hdc) (at <bfeb5fdca71942e18134223465f4f838>:0)
System.Drawing.Font.FromHfont (System.IntPtr hfont) (at <bfeb5fdca71942e18134223465f4f838>:0)
System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () (at <bfeb5fdca71942e18134223465f4f838>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_DefaultFont () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Font () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_FontHeight () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_PreferredHeight () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_DefaultSize () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor (System.Boolean autoInstallSyncContext) (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase..ctor () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox..ctor () (at <7ba8bff9dfdb4207a1717d1c6879c3ed>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.TextBox..ctor()
System.Windows.Forms.TextInputDialog..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/TextInputDialog.cs:20)
TileMaker.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TileMaker.cs:122)
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem, my best guess is that there are missing library dependencies. Without being able to see exactly what in the constructor could throw the exception, I in my limited knowledge fail to reach that solution. Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not using [Unity UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html)?

Comment: @derHugo That is what I currently have but I am going through an over hall to improve the aesthetics, and since the majority of the project uses windows forms I chose to continue doing so for uniformity. Pulse it seems like an interesting problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps [Unity WinForms](https://github.com/Meragon/Unity-WinForms)